Identify Short Animated Film: 2 Bugs on a Windshield save Kidnapped Girl
Anyone remember an animated film I think was on Atom Films. It had a bee or a moth or a butterfly that hit a windshield and is dying and talks to another bug that is trapped under the wiper. They are talking about life and doing something more with it and then the driver uses his wipers to clean up the guts, it smears and he can't see and crashes. The driver dies and the trunk pops open and a kid napped girl is set free. (maybe was around 2002-2003).
It was flash animation I believe, I actually thought this video was it at the beginning but it was not. The bug had a high pitched voice over. I remember there even being a fake commentary (animated as well) where the Bumble Bee that played the bug talked about how difficult it was playing the role (I think the Bee was dressed up like a Moth or Butterfly).     
The opening scene was a guy driving down the road with the radio playing. The song gets interrupted by a news report talking about a missing girl. He turns off the radio and then the bug hits the window and the camera spends most of the film from then on on the 2 bugs on the windshield. At the end when the bug dies, his guts are leaking out and the driver turns on the wipers. The other bug is freed from under them and the window gets really smeared, he hits a tree and the girl jumps out of the trunk. My family thinks I am crazy but there is no way I dreamt up this plot - it has to exist :)
I would be grateful if someone can tell me the name or a link to it.

I think I vaguely remember something similar... However, since AtomFilms is no more, some of their flash cartoons might not be online anymore. And TBH I'm not even sure web animation is on-topic here. :(

Nevermind, I found it. Let's just hope it's on-topic for now. ;) [It's on IMDb, which might be in its favor.]

It's called Bumble Beeing (The Butterfly Effect). A bumblebee hits a windshield and talks to a butterfly that's stuck under the wiper before being wiped to death, and it turns out to be a kidnapper's car when he crashes it and a little girl pops out of the trunk. Here's the full short:



And here's the butterfly's commentary on it:



